# XNA - How to use One Rectangle in sprites for collisions

Tags: xna, collision-detection

I'm new to XNA and game development in general. If I want to make an object solid so my character cannot pass through it, I would use several Rectangles to make the collision more "realistic"

What I do is to use the method Intersects() with both;

This are two Rectangles that will be solid. (Highlighted in Red):

[image]

And I wonder if there is a way to use one rectangle to achieve something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not. By definition, a rectangle has four points, and the new figure has six.

[image]

This is something to do with the library, however you could most likely create a wrapper around a few rectangles that has a similar API to the XNA rectangle class. This, I think, is the only way to accomplish something like this excepting @SteveH's solution.

Comment: Ball (circle) or Round corners collision use other similar methods? are they built in XNA? For example, if I have a Race game, and a track where you can collide with the round corners

Comment: There's a Sphere class for 3D, however natively XNA does not support circles. There is a library called Monogame that aims to be the open source, multiplatform version of XNA that is contemplating adding a circle class, however. That can be seen here: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/pull/3419

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can do something like this:

```
If(not in red rectangle)
   return;//no collision
else
   if(not in blue rectangle)
       //run collision code
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another trick that can be helpful:

If you plan to set up a large group of these, you can first test a rectangle that encompasses the component rectangles, then test the interior rectangles individually.

[image]

For `P[1]` we check whether it intersects `R[ab]`. Since it doesn't we don't have to check `R[a]` or `R[b]`.

`P[2]` intersects `R[ab]`, so we have to check `R[a]` and `R[b]`.

`P[3]` intersects `R[ab]`, so we check `R[a]` and `R[b]` and find `R[b]` intersects it.

If `R` contained a lot of rectangles, we could save a lot of time by checking the union first.

Comment: Yes, I'm now making a new class called "SolidSprite" public SolidSprite(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Rectangle[] collisionRectangles) to implement this idea